# the curve $y=x^2\cos{4x}$ for $0 \leq x \leq \dfrac{\pi}{8}$. The point $P$ is the maximum

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods

Question a) Show that the $x$ coordinates of $P$ satisfies the equation $4x^2\tan{4x}=2x$

b) Show also the $x$ coordinates of $P$ satisfies the equation $x=\dfrac{1}{4}\tan^{-1}(1/2x)$

I have been stuck on this question for the past hour I don't understand it it is the last section of my A level book chapter 6 and I have no professor and the back of my book all that is written is proof. Any help is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: (b) is just a rewriting of (a). So you only need to show that (a) is true.

Comment: @Allawonder okay how do we do that. and why would the book ask it as 2 separate questions

Comment: It is very obvious. Divide both sides by $4x^2,$ and take inverse tangents.

Comment: @Allawonder how do you divide 2x by 4x2 what would that be?

Comment: Are you allows to use calculus.  $y' = 2x\cos 4x - 4x^2\sin 4x$. so the max occurs when $2x\cos 4x = 4x^2\sin 4x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max occurs when $y'(x) = 0$.

The product rule of derivatives says that derivative of $\color{green}{f(x)}\color{red}{g(x)} = \color{green}{f(x)'}\color{red}{g(x)}+\color{green}{f(x)}\color{red}{g(x)'}$

And the chain rule says the derivative $\color{blue}{g({\color{orange}{h(x)}})}$ id $\color{blue}{g'({\color{orange}{h(x)}})}\color{orange}{h'(x)}$

$\color{green}{x^2} \color{red}{\cos 4x} $ is

$\color{green}{(x^2)'}\color{red}{\cos 4x} + \color{green}{x^2}\color{red}{(\cos 4x)'}=$

$\color{green}{(2x)}\color{red}{\cos 4x} + \color{green}{x^2}\color{red}{(\color{blue}{\cos}\color{orange}{4x})'}=$

$\color{green}{(2x)}\color{red}{\cos 4x} + \color{green}{x^2}\color{red}{(\color{blue}{\cos'}\color{orange}{4x})'}\color{orange}{(4x)'}=$

$\color{green}{(2x)}\color{red}{\cos 4x} + \color{green}{x^2}\color{red}{(\color{blue}{-\sin}\color{orange}{4x})'}\color{orange}{4}=$

$\color{green}{2x}\color{red}{\cos 4x} - \color{orange}4\color{green}x^2\color{green}{\sin(\color{orange}{4x})}$

So for $P$ to be the maximum is must occur at $(x, y)$ where $y'(x) = \color{green}{2x}\color{red}{\cos 4x} - \color{orange}4\color{green}x^2\color{green}{\sin(\color{orange}{4x})}=0$.

So that means $2x \cos 4x = 4x^2 \sin 4x$

So $2x = 4x^2 \frac {\sin 4x}{\cos 4x} = 4x^2 \tan 4x$.

That's a)

If we assume $x \ne 0$ then we can

Divide both sides by $4x^2$ to get

$\frac 1{2x} = \tan 4x$.

Take the $\arctan$ of both sides

$\arctan \frac 1{2x} = 4x$.  (Need to note that $-\frac \pi 2 < 4x < \frac \pi 2$ so $\tan $ is invertable)

So $x = \frac 14 \arctan \frac 1{2x}$.

That's $b$.

But what if $x = 0$.  Well, the book is sort of wrong.  $\frac 1{2x}$ is not defined but $\tan {\frac \pi 2} = \infty$ so if we extend $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{2x} = \infty$ and allow for $\arctan \infty = 0$ then we will have

$x =0  = \frac 14 0 = \frac 14\arctan \infty = \frac 14\arctan (\lim_{w\to 0} \frac 1{2w})$, so the book is sort of right if we are allowed to say the *scary* things like $\frac 1{2\cdot 0} = \infty$ and $\arctan \infty = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much I appricate it!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* The maximum of the given curve occurs wherever $y'=0,$ since $y=0$ at both endpoints of the domain.

Comment: What do i do with that i tries doing 0=x^2cos4x but it didn't work out

Comment: @Emily Do you know how to differentiate functions? In particular do you know the "product rule"?

Comment: the product rule of 4x^2tan4x-2x=0? how is that I know the product rule but to this

Comment: The product rule says if $y(x) = x^2 \cos 4x$ then $y'(x) = (x^2)'\cos 4x + x^2(\cos 4x)' = 2x\cos 4x - 4x^2 \sin 4x$.  Set that equal to $0$ and you get a) right away.  Divide and take the arc tan and divide again and you get part b.  (When $x \ne 0$).

Comment: Thank you very much I appricate it!