# Use integration by parts twice $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{8}}x^2\cos(4x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am confuse about this integration by two parts I don't get the steps and any help would be much appreciated  i know the answer is 0.00730 but don't know how to get to it. This is the work
[image]

Comment: Hint: both times, you should set $u$ equal to the polynomial. Then, you should get an integral purely in terms of trigonometric functions, which shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE.
You can differentiate $x^2$ and integrate $\cos(4x)$ using the formula. Then, do it another time with $x$ and $\sin(4x)$ and you will be done.

Comment: @Joe i have been looking at this so long that I am confused I need to visually see it but thank you! I appreciate how you are trying to help me.

Comment: @Flewer47 Thank you i think i am gonna love it here. but I am a bit confused on what you mean.

Comment: Please add an attempt/ your working into the post @Emily [see here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and welcome to MSE!

Comment: Meta comment. It's unfair helping (With FIVE answers!) a user (who shows no effort at all) just because they use a female nickname, while others are closed five minutes after asking.

Comment: @Raffaele I Know from your side it looks like I am putting no effort the reason I didn't answer is because I went down to eat I have been doing math for the past 3 hours and am working on this question right now and I don't know how to attach my work I appreciate everyone who is helping me because I have CAIE A levels and I got A last year in pure mathematics and I don't understand my teachers explanation and I hope to get good grades this year. I am sorry if it bothers you that I got help and 1 answer would be enough but each answer uses a different method which expand the way you look at it.

Comment: OP is getting their homework done by (high level) contributors https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034477/the-curve-y-x2-cos4x-for-0-leq-x-leq-dfrac-pi8-the-point-p-is-t/4034512?noredirect=1#comment8332195_4034512

Comment: @Emily What you said just now was really useful as it helps us understand where this question comes from. Just to clarify, are you retaking A level maths this year or are you taking Further Maths instead?

Comment: @Raffaele I actually have no homework as we are really behind in math and I am doing this my self as with the rate my class is going we will never finish the book this is the last question from the chapter then I will be moving on to Further calculus and yes it is related. And thank you for helping me on the last one I really appreciated it:)

Comment: @Toby Mak I am taking CAIE A level so I took pure mathematics 1and statistics last year AS level  and this year I am taking pure mathematics 2 and 3 and statistics 2 and 3

Comment: @Raffaele: Erm ... I didn't post an answer because Emily has a female nickname. I posted an answer because I like helping people by giving hints. That's something I do even if I haven't seen any effort on the OP's part, because often I see people engage with the material if they are given a push in the right direction. I also did not upvote this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do the first iteration for you. Set
\begin{align}
u &= x^2 & \frac{dv}{dx}&=\cos(4x) \\
\frac{du}{dx} &= 2x & v&=\frac{1}{4}\sin(4x)
\end{align}
Hence, the integral equals
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/8} u\frac{dv}{dx} \, dx &= \left[uv\right]_{0}^{\pi/8} - \int_{0}^{\pi/8} v\frac{du}{dx} \, dx \\
\int_{0}^{\pi/8} x^2\cos(4x) \, dx &= \left[\frac{1}{4}x^2\sin(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8} - \int_{0}^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{2}x\sin(4x) \, dx
\end{align}
Now set $u=\frac{1}{2}x$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}=\sin(4x)$. Let me know how you get on.

---

Let $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{2}x \sin(4x) \, dx \, .$$
If we set $u=\frac{1}{2}x$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}=\sin(4x)$, then we get that $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $v=-\frac{1}{4}\cos(4x)$. Hence,
\begin{align}
I &= \left[-\frac{1}{8}x\cos(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8} + \int_{0}^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{8} \cos(4x) \, dx \\
&= 0 + \int_{0}^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{8} \cos(4x) \\
&= \left[\frac{1}{32}\sin(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8} \\
&= \frac{1}{32}\sin(\pi/2) \\
&= \frac{1}{32} \, .
\end{align}
Hence,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/8} x^2\cos(4x) &= \left[\frac{1}{4}x^2\sin(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8} - \frac{1}{32} \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{256}-\frac{1}{32} \\
&= \frac{\pi^2 - 8}{256} \, .
\end{align}

Comment: So i did what you said and u= 1/2x   dv/dx= sin4x   du/dx=1/2 and   v =-1/4cos(4x) then I did the uv = which I got $1/2x-1/4cos(4)x=-1/8xcos(4x)$ and vdu/dx =$-1/8 cos(4x)$ and when I put the two together did =-1/8xcos(4x)+1/8cos(4x)= x and I the integrated $ \left[\frac{1}{4}x^2\sin(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8}$ -x but I got -0.354 i think I did something wrong

Comment: @Emily: Because we are working with a definite integral, you should get $$\int_{0}^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{2}x\sin(4x) \, dx = \left[-\frac{1}{8}x\cos(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8}+ \int_{0}^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{8}\cos(4x) \, dx \, .$$Is that what you got?

Comment: @Emily: Sorry, I made a tiny mistake in the above comment, but I have updated it now; please make sure it matches what you have wrote.

Comment: yes but the -1/8 i got -1/8x as I multiplies 1/2x by the -1/4cos(4x) and what I thout i should do is add the two and what was left over is x

Comment: Yes then i got what you did and did it and got x left over I think you arent spouse to add it but don't know what to do otherwise

Comment: @Emily: I don't quite understand what you mean. What did you get for $$\left[-\frac{1}{8}x\cos(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8} \, ?$$

Comment: so I got that but i was like what would you do with the 1/8cos(4x)dx what is its purpose so I thought you should add them

Comment: @Emily: What do you mean by purpose? Just evaluate it at $\pi/8$ and $0$.

Comment: i did now and i got 0.0147 i did $= \left[\frac{1}{4}x^2\sin(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8}$ -$ \left[\frac{-1}{8}x\cos(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8}$

Comment: this question seems hopeless

Comment: @Emily: I can help you get to the end but you need to be really clear. Can you just summarise everything you have done to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/8}\frac{1}{2}x\sin(4x) \, dx \, ? $$

Comment: well i think its wrong but once I got $ \left[\frac{-1}{8}x\cos(4x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8}$ i filled in x with pie/8 into the equation and minused it but the equation with x being filled with $0$

Comment: I will add a picture of my work on to the question so you can see.

Comment: @Emily: Having looked through your work on the second integration, it seems to me that there are two problems: I'm unsure if you have evaluated $uv$ at the points $\pi/8$ and $0$; also, it is not clear that you have worked out $\int_{0}^{\pi/8} v\frac{du}{dx} \, dx \, .$

Comment: i know there is something wrong with it but I don't know how to fix it I am very confused

Comment: I know you want me to solve it by myself but do you think you could show me how to solve it and where I went wrong so I can evaluate and and learn beacese now I am going in circles.if it is not too much to ask. Thank you. i am sorry for not getting it and being such a hastle

Comment: @Emily: See my updated answer. Please read through it carefully.

Comment: Ow my god i didnt use the chain rule and I wasn't able to put the equations together. I will never forget this after being stuck for so long. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Emily: You're welcome. I'd suggest practising some more of these problems, as they are rather tricky. Integration is the hardest chapter in A-level maths, so once you can crack it, you should feel comfortable with the rest of the course.

Comment: Thank you where would you suggest i get problems and if I just finished chapter 6 and the last chapter of the book is 11 do you think I can still catch up and do good in the may 6 exam?

Comment: @Emily: I'm afraid I can't give you any specific advice because it appears that you are taking a different specification to me. I think your teachers would be better placed to help you in that regard.

Comment: okay thank you anyway

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

When trying $$\int u'v\,dx=uv-\int uv'\,dx$$ you need to choose what functions $u$ and $v$ are. Here, you have two choices:

- $u=\dfrac{x^3}3,v=\cos(4x)$ or
- $u=\dfrac{\sin(4x)}4,v=x^2$.

In the first case, the new integral will even be harder because of the factor $x^3$. In the second case, $x^2$ will be differentiated to $2x$, and the degree lowers. (The other factor always remains an easy trigonometric function.) You can hope that a second application of integration by parts will reduce $x$ to $1$. Try that.

---

Using this trick, all integrals of the forms

$$\int P(x)\,e^{ax}\,dx,\int P(x)\cos(ax)\,dx,\int P(x)\sin(ax)\,dx$$

where $P$ is a polynomial can be solved.

Comment: Integrals such as $\int e^x \sin x \, dx$ can also be solved by what I like to call 'integration by parts déjà vu'. Setting $u$ equal to the trigonometric function twice gives you a formula for the integral expressed in terms of itself...

Comment: @Joe: right. This deserves to be explained to beginners, as they might believe that they are just circling in rounds. Also works with $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for the area of the circle, with the other trick $\int v\,dx=\int x'\cdot v\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

The tabular method (or the DI method) is great for integrals that require integration by parts multiple times:

\begin{array}{ccc}
& \text D & \text I \\
+ & \color{blue}{x^2} & \cos4x \\
- & \color{red}{2x} & \color{blue}{\frac14\sin4x} \\
+ & \color{green}{2} & \color{red}{-\frac1{16}\cos4x} \\
- & 0 & \color{green}{-\frac1{64}\sin4x}
\end{array}

From this we know that $$\int x^2\cos4x\,dx=\frac14x^2\sin4x+\frac18x\cos4x-\frac1{32}\sin4x+C.$$

Since this is a definite integral, simply evaluate the antiderivative from the bounds of integration (I will leave the work to you) and we have the result $$\frac1{256}(\pi^2-8).$$

Comment: I have never seen this method it seems so simple where can I learn more about this method because I understand how you got on to this answer but I don't get what you mean on how to continue it . I am sorry it takes time for me to understand and continue but I belive this method is something I want to learn well as it is done so gracefully

Comment: @Emily: BlackPenRedPen has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I-_SV8cwsw) on it. You don't need it for A-level, but it does speed things up,

Comment: @Joe I will definitly look at it because time is the hardest part of A levels the key is to make everything as fast and simple as possible.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The integral is $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{8}}x^2\cos(4x)dx$.
Let $u(x)=x^2$ and $v'(x)=\cos(4x)$. In those case, always differentiate the polynomial and integrate the trigonometric function.

We have $u'(x)=2x$, and a possible candidate for $v$ is $v(x)=\frac14\sin(4x)$.
Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{8}}x^2\cos(4x)dx
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{8}}u(x)v'(x)dx\\
&=\left[u(x)v(x)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{8}}-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{8}}u'(x)v(x)dx\\
&=\left[x^2 \times\frac14\sin(4x)\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{8}}-\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}8}x\sin(4x)dx
\end{align}

Evaluate the bracket, then use again an integration by parts for the second integral.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from IBP, a much nicer way of doing it is Feynman's trick (differentiation under the integral sign).

Let $I(k) = -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}8} \cos kx dx = - \frac 1k\sin \frac{k\pi} 2$

Then the required integral is $(\frac{d^2}{dk^2}I(k)) \vert_{k=4}$

which would after differentiating twice and substituting $k=4$ give the required answer of $\frac 1{256} (\pi^2 - 8)$